# Shows only one Location permission alert

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, info-plist

I want my application to take location in active and background modes (if use only **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription** permission then **myLocationButton** don't show).
I set  in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) location use</string>
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
```

And add MapViewController

```
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

But when the application starts, only the first Location permission alert is displayed, and the second permission alert appears after the application is reopened.

Update:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 ...    
 locationManager.delegate = self
 locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 viewMap.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)
        self.startLocationUpdates()
 ...
}

func startLocationUpdates() {
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.activityType = CLActivityType.automotiveNavigation
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = distanceFilterMetr
    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        let myLocation: CLLocation = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as! CLLocation
        viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: myLocation.coordinate, zoom: observeZoom)
        mapRoute.coordinateLatitude = myLocation.coordinate.latitude
        mapRoute.coordinateLongitude = myLocation.coordinate.longitude
        viewMap.delegate = self
        viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true
        viewMap.settings.compassButton = true
        didFindMyLocation = true
}
```

Comment: You only need to request "always" authorisation. This gives your app permission to use location in the foreground and the background.

Comment: @Paulw11 I write about if use only NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription permission then myLocationButton don't show (location update but button don`t show) iOS 10.3 swift 3

Comment: How are you deciding whether to show that button? I can assure you that Always authentication is all that is required for foreground and background location.

Comment: @Paulw11 please update my code. THANKS!!!

Comment: What property are you observing?  Why are you using KVO?

Comment: @Paulw11 I use [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/google-maps-api-tutorial/) They say "The current location of the user is described by a property of the map view object named myLocation. The good news regarding this property is that is a KVO-compliant (key-value observing compliant), meaning that we simply have to observe for changes on its value, and that way we’ll be able to know when the user’s location gets updated. I"

Comment: Notice in the tutorial they implement the `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` delegate method and use that to enable the mylocation button. Did you implement that method and make the change for "always" authorisation that you are requesting?

Comment: @Paulw11 THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! Yes, I forgot to change to always! My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Add this delegate in your class:

```
CLLocationManagerDelegate
```

Now inside you class:

```
var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var map = GMSMapView()
var currentLatitude:Double!
var currentLongitude:Double!
```

After that add this in your code:

```
override func loadView() {

    print("loadView called")

    // Enable some map settings

    map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    map.settings.myLocationButton = true
    map.settings.compassButton = true
    map.settings.scrollGestures = true
    map.settings.zoomGestures = true
    map.delegate = self

    view = map
}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("ViewDidLoad called")

    // Configuring location manager.

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    print("locationManager function called")

    // Fetch current location coordinates

    let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = (locationManager.location?.coordinate)!
    currentLatitude = locValue.latitude
    currentLongitude = locValue.longitude
    print("Current Location = \(currentLatitude!), \(currentLongitude!)")

    // Zoom to current location

    let target = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLatitude!, longitude: currentLongitude!)
    map.camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: target, zoom: 17)

    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

}
```

After adding this code, right click your Info.plist and "Open as source code". Add this in your Info.plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>googlechromes</string>
    <string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSContactsUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSMotionUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSRemindersUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSSiriUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSSpeechRecognitionUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSVideoSubscriberAccountUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```